# My session object is not cleared

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my controller I want to clear my object "parking" :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = "parking", types = { Parking.class })
@RequestMapping("/parking")
public class ParkingController {

    /**
     * vue parking.html
     */
    private static final String VIEW_PARKING = "parking";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "clearForm" })
public String clearForm(@ModelAttribute("parking") Parking parking,
        final HttpSession httpSession, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    sessionStatus.setComplete();    
    return VIEW_PARKING;
}
```

I have tried the `sessionStatus.setComplete();`but also the `httpSession.invalidate()` but my object is still filled with my previous entries when the page is reloaded.

Here is an example of the html code filled by the parking content:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/parking}"
    th:object="${parking}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    name="clearForm">Remise à zéro du formulaire</button>
</div>

<input type="text" th:field="*{email.destinataires}"
    class="form-control" />
```

`email` being an attribute of the `parking` object

In debug mode I've already checked that the code shown is executed.

Comment: May be your browser captured those data. Check your object exist in that session by getting the object in controller. Better approach is remove that object from session. Invalidate session is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Nhu Vy solution was nearly good, I just had to add a get redirect in order that the solution works fine :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"clearForm"})
public String clearForm(@ModelAttribute("parking") Parking parking, WebRequest request, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    request.removeAttribute("parking", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
    return "redirect:/" +VIEW_PARKING;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may confused `@SessionScope` with `@RequestScope`. Latter one is invalidated between page reloads automatically.